# jquery function .html .text not working when ajax call inside .each

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using a jquery ajax function to get data from server , and then loop through the array and update HTML elements.

The return data cant update.

```
$(document).delegate("#update_balance_btn", "click", function(event){

    $.ajax({
        url : base_url + "login/get_data",
        type : 'POST',
        success : function(data) {              
            $.each(JSON.parse(data) , function(index, val) { 
              $(".return_balance").text(val + " update success");
              //$('.return_balance').empty().append(val + " update success" );
              console.log(val);  // I can console log all the data 
              //$(".return_balance").html( val + " update success");  
// not wokirng , the val is not inserted to html , only " update success" is inserted 
            });
        },
        error : function(request,error){
            console.log(  JSON.stringify(request) );
        }
    });
});
```

I can get the data after each function, `.html` can update the string "update success" but just cant insert val inside the html element.

my html element

```
     <li class="list-group-item">1: <span class="return_balance"> 0 </span></li>
    <li class="list-group-item">2: <span class="return_balance"> 0 </span> </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">3: <span class="return_balance"> 0 </span> </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">4Casino : <span class="return_balance"> 0 </span> </li>
```

any help will be highly appreciated thanks

[image]

Comment: can you show what's in `console.log(val)`?

Comment: updated inside the post bro.

Comment: can you post your success response?

Comment: what do you get when you console.log(data[index]);

Comment: @Leong I honestly can't see what's wrong. Do you think you can create a jsfiddle page to showcase your issue?

Comment: Try to use id instead of classes if you are updating data to unique DOM elements.

Comment: @ShiWei why should he/she use `id` attribute? when he has `jquery` and wants to do same operation on multiple elements he must use `class`

Comment: @Kenny hmm, you have a point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is, you are replacing the text of all elements that has class `return_balance`

Assuming you are getting data from the API, and from screenshot, you can write something like

```js
$.each(JSON.parse(data) , function(index, val) { 
     $(".return_balance").eq(index).html(val + " update success");
});
```

If you still didn't get the desired output, just post the error and output you get after this

Comment: hi can get the data now , thanks , what its the root cause ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Give an ID to each `span` element you want to update with your results. Then select each span by the ID.

Your code just update all elements in each iteration. So, of course, you will see only the last updated value every where.

```
 $.each(JSON.parse(data) , function(index, val) { 
    $(".return_balance #" + index).text(val + " update success");
});


<li class="list-group-item">1: <span class="return_balance" id="1"> 0 </span></li>
<li class="list-group-item">2: <span class="return_balance" id="2"> 0 </span> </li>
<li class="list-group-item">3: <span class="return_balance" id="3"> 0 </span> </li>
<li class="list-group-item">4Casino : <span class="return_balance" id="4"> 0 </span> 
</li>
```

Answer (score -1):

It's because your changing the text of all span with a class of 'return_balance'. The last returned val is 0 so the final value of all  is also 0. Though the result you've posted has a '1102.07' right ?

Comment: His problem is not showing the val at all. Check the comment in his code

Comment: @TreeNguyen, why you down voted it ? There's no error in his code and it seems his logic also has a problem.